# Klarna Checkout - Struck on Shipping Step in Multi Website - Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, checkout, shipping, shipping-methods, klarna

I'm reaching out to point out the Checkout issue in our Multi-website Magento 2.3.5 Setup. It is not allowing us to proceed further on the second website and showing an error on the Shipping Step.

Default store view :- Swedish ✔ - Working correctly
New Store View :- Danish  x - Doesn't working

**Error**
This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.

[image]

When i have debug it further following error is displaying by klarna "Shipping service Failed"
I'm sure that I have added the country to allowed list,

**Shipping Methods**
Flat Rate
Free Shipping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution it was due to the URL's that were getting blocked, in other words our website was not accessible on web due to some restrictions. As soon as we removed those restrictions the issue was gone & it was working now we are able to place an order